# Inserting data in a Dictionary with raw_input dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am writing a code for my school project where user enters the data for a student along with numbers for three subject and if needed can update them later. I have 2 questions.

1) How to insert the key value pair into the dictionary when all inputs are in one line of the console?

Ex:-

> ```
>  >>>Enter the data?
>  >>>Alex 45 26 35
> ```

Here key is 'Alex' and values are 45 26 35

Expected output

> ```
>  {'Alex': '45 62 35'}
> ```

2) Perform update from single command line statement?

with syntax  >>>'Action' 'data'

Ex:-

> ```
>    >>>Update Alex 45 47 41
> ```

the main problem i am facing here is how to split the statement in Action and data so that program can identify them individually and further data into a key value pair?

Comment: This is not a coding service

Comment: Hint: 1) Split your input and check if it has 4 or 5 items. 5 items means it contains Update 2) Better solution, split your input and check if the first item is `Update`... If you have problems about `how to split`, then google "python split"...

Comment: @kezzos I am not asking for the service! FYI, if you haven't understood the que, i only want to know to the correct statement to add a data into a dictionary from a single line taken from a raw_input. If you dont know plz give your valuable advice on other portals.

Comment: @FallenAngel i tried split function but data endsup in List format and on type castin it to dicttionary it report error as 
>                           p1=raw_input('-->')
>                           p2=dict(p1.split(' '))
>                           ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: @CbK if you have a list, then you can use list indexes to reach the value you want. Examine the first item in the list, if it is update, then you should update your dict and person name is in the second index. If it is not an update, then person name is in the first index. Rest are values. Join the remianing values using (white space). You must read list and dict operations. There are simpler ways to achieve this and you can learn them if you read.

Comment: @FallenAngel Yes, i was trying to do the same but was not able to insert the data into a dictionary into a typecasting error. 
thanks i will dig more deeper into list & dict operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to split the string at the first space, then you can use the `string.split(s, maxsplit=n)` where s is the string to split by and `maxsplit=n` is the number of splits to stop at. If you do not give any value for `s` that is only call the function as `string.split(maxsplit=n)` then it would split by all whitespaces.

Example -

```
>>> s = "Alex 45 26 35"
>>> s.split(maxsplit=1)
['Alex', '45 26 35']
```

You can use this to split the strings and then use first element as key and second as value in your dictionary (if that is what you really want).

You can use similar logic in your `Actions` case as well, split the input at first space, and then the first element of the return of split would be the action, and the second element would be the `data` .

To create dictionary from the list, you can use multiple methods, like -

```
 d= dict([s.split(maxsplit=1)])
 d
 >>> {'Alex': '45 26 35'}
```

Or

```
d = {}
slst = s.split(maxsplit=1)
d[slst[0]] = d[slst[1]]
```

Comment: I tried this but it ends up being a list rather than a dictionary. If we type caste it, then it reports error below 
>                Stud_data=dict(s.split(maxsplit=1))
>                ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: Perfect, it works, now i would also be able to solve 2nd que. thanks :)